# spacing between GWT listgrid cells

Tags: smartgwt

I have a created a GWT listGrid and trying to override the behavior of spacing of the cells. By default there is no space among the cells of the grid.

I have already tried something like this and it didn't work.

Listgrid grid = new Listgrid();

grid.setStyleName("my-listgrid-style");

and in css I have defined  border-spacing: 10px for my-listgrid-style.

How do I have space between the cells in the grid?

For example, here I am designing the grid which I wanted to implement that has space between column1 and column2:

-------------      -------------
 Header1        Header2
-------------      -------------
 
dataA1             dataA2

dataB1             dataB2

Answer (score 2):

You can apply style to listGrid..

```
.withlines td {
    padding: 2px 10px !important;
    border: 0.2px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 15px;
}

.withlines th {
    border: 0.2px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 10px !important;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 15px;
}

.withlines_medium td {
    padding: 2px 10px !important;
    border: 0.2px solid #E0E0E0 !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Is .withlines a special Smartgwt style for listgrids? Or just an example style name.  Something that bothers me is that SmartGWT widgets look for certain stylenames by default, and no idea what that is if you are trying to write your own CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simply modify td and th for my problem.  But this is only the text in the cell I've found.  Not sure if it would work in your case.

td,th {
    padding: 10px;
}